# Is there a way to checkout code from Bitbucker server (stash) from within Java code

Tags: java, bitbucket, vcs-checkout

We are maintaining some JavaScript code within BitBucket. We want to be able to checkout JavaScript code from Bitbucket and be able to access the .js file within our Java application.

Is there a way to checkout code using Java. Is there some library available which can do this for us.

For example, when I want to checkout a git repository from git client, I would execute the command git clone https://bitbucketserverhost/PROJECT/repo.git
This will create a folder with the repo name in current directory and checkout all the source files in that folder.

Is there a way to do git clone from within Java. Basically I want the Java code to read latest JavaScript files committed by developers within Bitbucket, access it as a file to be able to read its contents and then compare it with some other file.

Comment: Normally you would checkout everything together, and normally you would not be checking out JS code within your application.  Can you better describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: Run git as an external executable?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated my question. Yes I am trying to checkout everything together not just JS code. I just want some way to be able to checkout everything within git repository.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from adding those Java source files to your current Git repo?

Comment: yes the java source files belong to a different git repo and should not be committed to the repo containing JS files.

Comment: You could include the Java files repo as a submodule in the JS repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Eclipse's [jGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) library for checking out code from BitBucket in Java.
Added the below maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0.201706111038-r</version>
</dependency>
```

Below line of code can be used to code can be used to create a clone.

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import java.io.File;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CloneCommand clone = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(uri).setDirectory(new File(checkoutDir));
        try {
            clone.call();
        } 
        catch (GitAPIException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

where uri is the git URI of the repository that we use in git clone command.
It is important to note that I have not specified my credentials anywhere in the code because the repository was public. If the repo you are trying to clone, is not public, you need to add more code.